# Matrix in Latex

Tags: matrices

I am new to Latex, and I have been trying to get the matrix of following form

```
    [x11 x12 x13 . . . . x1n
     x21 x22 x23 . . . . x2n
     .
     .
     .
     .
     xd1 xd2 xd3 . . . . xdn]
```

Where the letters accompanying the elements are subscripts '11 12 13' etc. I tried it in the following fashion

```
    $$
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}&.&.&.&.&x_{1n}
```

And so on in similar fashion. I get errors when I use the above method and I know its amateurish. Can you please tell me how to get it done the right way? I even tried including '\' for the periods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Why is that? It gives proper context.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You must read at least [lshort](https://texdoc.org/serve/lshort/0) (page 58) or [amsldoc.pdf](https://texdoc.org/serve/amsldoc/0) Section 4 (page 12).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
    \hdotsfor{5} \\
    x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{d1} & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots  & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As an extension of this answer, a nice place to see the different matrix visuals is here: http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Matrix_environments

Comment: It's a good site, however I didn't see nothing about ellipsis in the matrix

Answer (score 23):

From the link @TobyStack gave:

I don't use the document/array package because I'm not very experienced.

new row:`\\` (btw, you can use that for `$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0\\j\ne i}^m\sum_{i=0}^n$`)
output: [image]

new column: `&`

Also, use

```
    line:     \ldots 
    diagonal: \ddots 
    vertical: \vdots
```

output:[image]

Depending on your preference:

```
    brackets: \begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}
    parentheses: \begin{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}
```

Screenshoot:[image]

Comment: The baseline spacing of the lower limit is a bit large.  You might take a look at `substack`, provided by `amsmath`, which should tighten things up a bit.