# How can I draw those line joining matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to draw something like this :

[image]

I have created matrix normally, from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204627/185862) :

```
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
\hdotsfor{5} \\
x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
```

But it doesn't give that 3D feeling and how can I create the those line between those matrices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome! You can use `tikz-3dplot` to install a view and the `3d` library of Ti*k*Z, which automatically gets loaded, to project the matrices on some planes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=2,transform shape]
 \node[inner xsep=-3pt,inner ysep=-0.3pt] (mat1){$\displaystyle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11}       & x_{12} \\
  x_{21}       & x_{22}  \\
  \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
 \node[inner xsep=-4pt,inner ysep=-0.3pt] (mat2){$\displaystyle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
  x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
  \hdotsfor{5} \\
  x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots & x_{dn}
  \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{scope}
\foreach \Y in {south,north} {\foreach \X in {west,east}
{\draw (mat1.\Y\space\X)  -- (mat2.\Y\space\X);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also install the background pattern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=2,transform shape]
 \node[inner xsep=-3pt,inner ysep=-0.3pt] (mat1){$\displaystyle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11}       & x_{12} \\
  x_{21}       & x_{22}  \\
  \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
 \node[inner xsep=-4pt,inner ysep=-0.3pt] (mat2){$\displaystyle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\
  x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
  x_{31}       & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
  x_{41}       & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} \\
  \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \foreach \Y in {south,north} {\foreach \X in {west,east}
 {\draw (mat1.\Y\space\X)  -- (mat2.\Y\space\X);}}
 \foreach \X in {1,2}
 {\fill[blue!20] (mat\X.west)  -- (mat\X.east) -- (mat\X.south east) 
  -- (mat\X.south) -- (mat\X.north) -- (mat\X.north west) -- cycle; }
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You seem to have problems with installing `tikz-3dplot`. While there should not be a problem, here is a possible workaround. Save [this file](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex) as `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` in the same directory as the file you are compiling. Then this should work, too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,3d,3dtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=70,psi=0,theta=70}]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=2,transform shape]
 \node[inner xsep=-3pt,inner ysep=-0.3pt] (mat1){$\displaystyle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11}       & x_{12} \\
  x_{21}       & x_{22}  \\
  \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
 \node[inner xsep=-4pt,inner ysep=-0.3pt] (mat2){$\displaystyle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\
  x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
  x_{31}       & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
  x_{41}       & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} \\
  \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \foreach \Y in {south,north} {\foreach \X in {west,east}
 {\draw (mat1.\Y\space\X)  -- (mat2.\Y\space\X);}}
 \foreach \X in {1,2}
 {\fill[blue!20] (mat\X.west)  -- (mat\X.east) -- (mat\X.south east) 
  -- (mat\X.south) -- (mat\X.north) -- (mat\X.north west) -- cycle; }
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the conventions for the angles may change in future revisions of the library. The problem is that different packages follow different conventions, which applies to e.g. `tikz-3dplot` and `pgfplots`. It is not clear what the "best" convention is. However, translating between these conventions is a pain.

Comment: Found it [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot?lang=en).



I couldn't install it : **LaTeX Error File `tikz-3dplot.sty' not found.  Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)  Enter file name: **

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad AFAIK `tikz-3dplot` is par of any standard TeX installation. How did you install LaTeX? Note that I am only using it to install a view, so in principle one could achieve the result also by installing the view with e.g. [this **experimental** library](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex).

Comment: I installed *TeXworkd* and that isntalled *MiKtex*..